# Automatically take down environment in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I need to make sure some kubernetes deployments will go down after 24 hours.

Right now I have a script that polls deployments and keeps the time it noticed it first.

Then after 24 hours it will try to kill it.

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered a side-car container that uses the `ServiceAccount` token to delete itself? Aside from that, are your needs that it must run a _total_ of 24 hours, meaning if the Pod gets rescheduled due to eviction, it still has to run for the "balance" of its time?

Comment: why would you like to change your approach? There is nothing wrong with having a "controller" that watches for deployments that match a certain pattern and kill them if they are too old! (just make sure you're actually only getting the ones you have to kill ;-) ) This you can run as a deployment itself (write it in go or whatever programming or scripting language you like) and have it check the kubernetes API...